# Can't start KVM guest: "network 'default' is not active"

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I use Virtual Machine Manager (virt-manager).

- Host: Ubuntu 18.04.
- Guest: Windows.

After first shutdown I can't start it. I get this error message:

```
Error starting domain: Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 125, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 82, in newfn
```

Comment: Start the virtual network `default` and, if it fails to start, also post the error that you receive.

Comment: @Michael Hampton you're right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 39):

First, confirm that the default network is indeed inactive:

```
sudo virsh net-list --all
```

If so, start the default network:

```
sudo virsh net-start default
```

Run the first command line again to see if it worked.

Comment: Hi there! How can I make it start with boot?

Comment: @Rumen I believe it is `sudo virsh net-autostart default`